# How to plot mean CPUE for multiple species with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out the best way to plot mean CPUE for the top 5 most abundant species by year. I was able to plot these all separately, but it requires a lot of code and gets messy and I can't figure out how to get them all on the same figure.

This is a subset of my data

```
structure(list(year = c(2011, 2016, 2016, 2009, 2016, 2016, 2011, 
                               2009, 2014, 2008, 2011, 2016, 2012, 2017, 2008, 2009, 2018, 2018, 
                               2016, 2012, 2013, 2012, 2016, 2013, 2017, 2012, 2016, 2009, 2008, 
                               2011, 2010, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2015, 2013, 2014, 2008, 2013, 
                               2018, 2013, 2013, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2017, 2010, 2008, 2013, 2013, 
                               2018, 2011, 2015, 2009, 2010, 2013, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2008, 2010, 
                               2011, 2015, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2016, 2008, 2018, 2012, 2013, 2012, 
                               2016, 2016, 2014, 2010, 2012, 2011, 2013, 2015, 2015, 2009, 2010, 
                               2009, 2008, 2016, 2017, 2008, 2012, 2015, 2008, 2016, 2017, 2014, 
                               2009, 2009, 2011, 2012, 2012), Commonname = c("Grass Porgy", 
                                                                             "Sand Perch", "Lane Snapper", "Scallops", "Striped Burrfish", 
                                                                             "Dusky Pipefish", "Eucinostomus", "Scallops", "Dusky Pipefish", 
                                                                             "Gulf Toadfish", "White Grunt", "Black Sea Bass", "Silver Perch", 
                                                                             "Eucinostomus", "Pigfish", "Banded Blenny", "Black Sea Bass", 
                                                                             "Spotted Seatrout", "Bay Scallop", "Fringed Filefish", "Planehead Filefish", 
                                                                             "Pigfish", "Grass Porgy", "Bighead Searobin", "Lane Snapper", 
                                                                             "Scallops", "Southern Puffer", "Dusky Pipefish", "Pigfish", "Pinfish", 
                                                                             "Pink Shrimp", "Spotted Seatrout", "Pink Shrimp", "Inshore Lizardfish", 
                                                                             "Bay Scallop", "Lined Sole", "White Grunt", "Spotted Seatrout", 
                                                                             "Gulf Toadfish", "Lined Sole", "Pinfish", "Gulf Toadfish", "Pinfish", 
                                                                             "Pigfish", "Fringed Filefish", "Fringed Filefish", "Atlantic Calico Scallop", 
                                                                             "Eucinostomus", "Pinfish", "Pink Shrimp", "Inshore Lizardfish", 
                                                                             "Portunus Crabs", "Scallops", "Dusky Pipefish", "Fringed Filefish", 
                                                                             "Pigfish", "Planehead Filefish", "Pigfish", "Silver Perch", "Fringed Pipefish", 
                                                                             "Spottail Pinfish", "Scrawled Cowfish", "Ocellated Moray", "Spottail Pinfish", 
                                                                             "Planehead Filefish", "White Grunt", "Spottail Pinfish", "Banded Blenny", 
                                                                             "Pink Shrimp", "Pigfish", "Hogfish", "Fringed Pipefish", "Grass Porgy", 
                                                                             "Gulf Pipefish", "Bay Scallop", "Orange Filefish", "Scallops", 
                                                                             "Polka-dot Batfish", "Gulf Toadfish", "Scallops", "Gulf Toadfish", 
                                                                             "Pigfish", "Silver Perch", "White Grunt", "Spottail Pinfish", 
                                                                             "Striped Burrfish", "Bandtail Puffer", "Scrawled Cowfish", "Chain Pipefish", 
                                                                             "Portunus Crabs", "Gulf Toadfish", "Scallops", "Dusky Pipefish", 
                                                                             "Spottail Pinfish", "Inshore Lizardfish", "Striped Burrfish", 
                                                                             "Inshore Lizardfish", "Spottail Pinfish", "Planehead Filefish", 
                                                                             "Banded Blenny"), CPUE = c(0.134916351861846, 0.149907057624273, 
                                                                                                        0.134916351861846, 0.404749055585537, 0.134916351861846, 1.19925646099418, 
                                                                                                        0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 0.539665407447383, 0.224860586436409, 
                                                                                                        0.404749055585537, 2.02374527792769, 1.34916351861846, 0.94441446303292, 
                                                                                                        0.224860586436409, 0.299814115248546, 0.149907057624273, 0.404749055585537, 
                                                                                                        0.149907057624273, 1.18051807879115, 2.02374527792768, 3.77765785213168, 
                                                                                                        0.963688227584612, 0.168645439827307, 0.337290879654614, 0.674581759309228, 
                                                                                                        0.168645439827307, 2.39851292198837, 0.674581759309228, 12.2923787251904, 
                                                                                                        0.168645439827307, 0.299814115248546, 0.269832703723691, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        2.02374527792768, 0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        0.269832703723691, 0.269832703723691, 1.51780895844576, 0.809498111171074, 
                                                                                                        1.07933081489477, 0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 0.674581759309228, 0.269832703723691, 
                                                                                                        0.149907057624273, 0.149907057624273, 0.224860586436409, 1.648977633867, 
                                                                                                        0.599628230497092, 1.4840798704803, 0.192737645516922, 0.674581759309228, 
                                                                                                        0.269832703723691, 1.04934940336991, 2.02374527792769, 0.149907057624273, 
                                                                                                        0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 5.26173772261198, 0.404749055585537, 
                                                                                                        4.34730467110392, 0.674581759309228, 0.134916351861846, 0.599628230497092, 
                                                                                                        1.07933081489477, 0.245302457930628, 0.269832703723691, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        0.449721172872819, 0.134916351861846, 0.269832703723691, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        1.79888469149128, 0.674581759309228, 0.134916351861846, 1.34916351861846, 
                                                                                                        0.269832703723691, 1.34916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        0.149907057624273, 0.134916351861846, 0.404749055585537, 0.134916351861846, 
                                                                                                        1.4840798704803, 1.34916351861846, 2.24860586436409, 0.168645439827307, 
                                                                                                        0.269832703723691, 0.149907057624273, 0.134916351861846, 4.04749055585537, 
                                                                                                        0.149907057624273, 0.674581759309228)), row.names = c(1:200), class = "data.frame")
```

I used this code on my entire dataset to pull out the mean CPUE for an individual species and then used the ggplot to get the figure below

```
pinfish <- df %>% 
  filter( Commonname == "Pinfish") %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(CPUE = mean(CPUE))
pinfish

ggplot(pinfish, aes(x=year, y= CPUE)) + 
  geom_line(aes()) +
  labs(title = "Annual Mean CPUE of Pinfish", y = "Mean CPUE (# fish/100m2)", x = "Date")+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Is it possible to create a plot with the mean CPUE for the top 5 most abundant species in my data set without having to manually separate each one of these species like I did above? And can these be combined into one plot with multiple lines or into separate plots that are side by side?

I found the top 5 most abundant species by filtering the data through excel, but I'm curious if there's a quick way to filter this in R? You probably wont get the same results with this subset of data, but if you could provide a code that would pull it, that would be great

The top 5 species that I detected in excel are: pinfish, pigfish, spottail pinfish, black sea bass, and dusky pipefish.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How do we see which species is common in the data? And what information is provided by the rownames?

Comment: The row names were generated when I made a sub-sample of my data, those are just the rows that it pulled for the random sample.. I'll take those out to remove the confusion.

Comment: No worries. See my answer below. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the most common species according to mean CPUE value over all years

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

most_common <- df %>%
  group_by(Commonname) %>% 
  summarise(mean_cpue = mean(CPUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(mean_cpue)) %>% 
  top_n(5) %>% 
  pull(Commonname)
```

Plot most common species:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Commonname, year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_CPUE_year = mean(CPUE)) %>% 
  filter(Commonname %in% most_common) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y= mean_CPUE_year)) + 
  geom_line(aes()) +
  labs(title = "Annual Mean CPUE of Pinfish", y = "Mean CPUE (# fish/100m2)", x = "Date")+
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~Commonname)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first half works great for finding the most common species. The second code runs, but instead of a smooth line like the example I showed above, it does this https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipN9hl-ylNsLUAnJd87liMhft0g8oOPEh_0bj_62

Comment: No worries. The link doesn't work for me. I added the plot above, do you get the same plot? What do you mean by "smooth"? By construction the line will be edgy since you only have one observation per year and only a few years. Or am I missing something?

Comment: "smooth" was poor wording.. I am looking for what your plot shows above. However when I run the code instead of having a line drawing it differently. I'll try adding the image into my original post to show you what I mean.

Comment: I see. I forgot to include the averaging that you did over species per year. I updated the code for the plot above. Does this now give a similar plot as shown in my answer?